# Move Store Domain from Magento

Tags: magento, dns, installation, cross-domain, move

We want to move a Domain (ex. www.abc.com) to another Magento Installation. For this Domain, there is a Shop running with products and already sales.

---

My question is:

When we move the domain (only the domain, no sales or products), does this have effect on the old magento installation?

Comment: many things to check if your question is only like that.

Answer (score 0):

No there will be no issue when you move your existing domain to new Magento Installation. If you want to connect your old Magento installation to any other domain, you need to change base url from `core_config_data` table in database.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering...

This domain is actually a addon shop... the standard shop will run on the old system only the domain (www.abc.com) will be moved... so this storeview dissapears... actually you think there are no problems then for the whole system?

Comment: Can you please explain with some example

Comment: the store is running with multiple storeviews... the main storeview is for example (www.main.com)... this should run as usual on this old system (magento 1.5.)... then we got a lot more storviews, for example (www.abc.com)... this domain should be now on the new system... my question is now --> are there any known issues, when we move this storeview?

Comment: okay means you have multiple store view and now one domain that is connected with one store view. You want to connect that store view with another magento installtion. If this is the case. there will be no issue.

Comment: Hey! if anybody faces the same problem.... The moving of the domain causes no errors...
thanks for help